# How to use text sent to console as input for a command line program that doesn't natively support that?

Tags: windows, console

I know a few console redirect parameters, such as `>`, `<` and `|`.

But I can't figure out a way to do it. As an example, let's say I wanted to copy a file using `copy`. The normal operation would be `copy sourceFile destinationFile`.
What if I wanted the source file to be input from console? Something like `copy <""File Contents here"" Destination file`. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

My application is more complex, but I think an example using the copy utility will be easier to understand.

Comment: What do you want to do with this command? What are your expected results? Do you want to copy some console input to a file, or copy a file whose name is arriving from the console into a known destionation? Or perhaps accept the source filename from a known file and copy to a known destination?

Comment: `copy con "file.ext"` copies the console input to a file `file.ext`; you cannot redirect anything into `copy` using `<` as it does not accept any data at the _STDIN_ (standard input) channel; the `find` command however reads _STDIN_ if no file is given: `find "search string"` awaits console input; `< "file.ext" find "search string"` redirects the file content into the _STDIN_ channel which is read by `find`; you can also write `find "search string" < "file.ext"`...

Comment: What I need to do is create a scheduled task based on a XML file, but instead of including the text file as an additional file, I'd like the contents to be sent via console.

The command is this:

`schtasks /create /tn "Test" /xml FilePath`